# What is the best way to install a pre-populated SQLite database in an Android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have a pre-populated SQLite database with approximately 124kb of data. I'm developing an Android application using Kotlin and Androids' Jetpack. The database won't be updated by the user once preloaded, it will only be updated on application update. What is the best, easy way to preload this database on first use of the app? Many of the ways I've seen are either Java oriented or really complicated.

Comment: Are you using Room? If so, see `createFromAsset()` on `RoomDatabase.Builder`.

Comment: No, I'm not using Room, it has error on compilation with Jetpack Compose. It is an issue with Jetpack Compose that is not resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Room Persistence Library, part of jetpack, it is fairly strain forward. Just call `.createFromAsset()` with `Room.databaseBuilder()`

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
.createFromAsset("myapp.db") //myapp.db in the assets folder
.build()
```

The room database will be populated using myapp.db

more from docs https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#kotlin

more about Room : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

Place your pre-populated SQLite database in project assets and after new app database creation create new empty DB and then copy it:

```
 String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.yourpackage.name/databases/";
 String DB_NAME = "some";

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open("database/some.db");

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```